# select2 does not close automatically after opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need my select2 to close if I click outside of it.
They asked me for a table in which if I select a material in the select, a new line is created and the new select is automatically opened, but when I do, it gets stuck even if I press outside.

$('this').closest('tr').next('tr').find('select:enabled').select2('open')

With this code, when I go from one line to another, the following select opens, but if I don't want to select anything, it stays open even if I click outside

I only need it to close if I click outside

Comment: Remember you can use the syntax highlighting feature of markdown to make your code snippets more readable. Also It might help to share the HTML of the DOM nodes you're trying to manipulate, or what you mean by 'stuck'

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. However, there is an invisible container that needs to be clicked in order to close the select2 menu. Perhaps your document's `<body>` does not extend the full height of the window. You could try using the style: `body: { min-height: 100vh; }` and see if that helps.